is Flutter Transparent/Translucent Background App no longer supported or more steps are needed
I am trying to create a flutter app with translucent or transparent background. I tried following instructions found in stackoverflow, and from ChatGPT. but only getting black background instead of seeing my phone's wallpaper underneath. so, I wanted to know if it is no longer support.
Direction on how to create translucent or transparent background flutter app, with the current Flutter version
AndroidManifest.xml
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|density|layoutDirection"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
    />
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>

styles.xml
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Transparent background -->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Transparent background -->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

MainActivity.kt

import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.view.WindowManager

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
    }
}

main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TransparentScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TransparentScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), // Adjust the opacity as needed
          child: Text(
            'Hello, World!',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I don't recall ever seeing the phone wallpaper.  When an app is running, the home page isn't visible at all.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Add these lines to styles.xml:
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>

and:
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>

And in MainActivity.kt override the following function:
override fun getTransparencyMode(): TransparencyMode {
    return TransparencyMode.transparent
}

No other manipulations with MainActivity are required.
